# Terraform v0.11.1 : Error downloading modules: Error loading modules: open .terraform/modules/3f10921295c292995128e9e36eb: no such file or directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have recently updated my terraform from v0.10.8 to v0.11.1

I am facing awkward issue while running terraform plan,
For first time running the command it gives me proper plan in output but while running the same command 2nd time it gives me below error while loading the module.

> Error downloading modules: Error loading modules: module zookeeper:
>   open .terraform/modules/3f10921295c292995128e9e36ebdfa9f: no such file
>   or directory

It looks like some issue of provider or module, But my terraform gets initialized successfully with below output.

> provider.aws: version = "~> 1.2" provider.template: version = "~> 1.0"

Please suggest any solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I found the solution.

We have to delete the old ***.terraform*** directory before the creation of the fresh plan.

Answer (score 4):

`$ terraform get -update`

`$ terraform refresh # Error is gone`