# terraform init not working when specifying modules

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am new to terraform and trying to fix a small issue which I am facing when testing modules.

Below is the folder structure I have in my local computer.

[image]

I have below code at storage folder level

```
#-------storage/main.tf

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my-first-terraform-bucket" {
    bucket = "first-terraform-bucket"
    acl = "private"
    force_destroy = true
}
```

And below snippet from main_code level referencing storage module

```
#-------main_code/main.tf

module "storage" {
    source = "../storage"
}
```

When I am issuing terraform init / plan / apply from storage folder it works absolutely fine and terraform creates the s3 bucket.

But when I am trying the same from main_code folder I am getting the below error -

```
main_code@DFW11-8041WL3: terraform init
Initializing modules...
- module.storage
Error downloading modules: Error loading modules: module storage: No Terraform configuration files found in directory: .terraform/modules/0d1a7f4efdea90caaf99886fa2f65e95
```

I have read many issue boards on stack overflow and other github issue forums but did not help resolving this. Not sure what I am missing!

Comment: [try deleting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48057222/terraform-v0-11-1-error-downloading-modules-error-loading-modules-open-terr) the `.terraform` folder in the `./storage` folder.  Also, if the `./storage` is a module, you do not need to include the `provider aws` section as it will be inherited from whatever code calls the module.

Answer (score 4):

Just update the existing modules by running `terraform get --update`. If this not work delete the .terraform folder.

Answer (score 3):

I agree the comments from @rclement.

Several ways to troubleshooting terraform issues.

1. Clean `.terraform` folder and rerun `terraform init`.

This is always the first choice. But it takes time when you run `terraform init` next time, it starts installing all providers and modules again.

2. If you don't want to clean `.terraform` to save the deployment time, you can run `terraform get --update=true`

Most case is, you did some changes in modules, and it need be refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue but the problem for me was, The module I have created was looking for the **providers.tf** so had to add it for the modules as well and it worked.

```
├── main.tf
├── modules
│   └── droplets
│       ├── main.tf
│       ├── providers.tf
│       └── variables.tf
└── variables.tf
```

So my providers was present in the root locations previous which modules could not use so the issue for me.

Comment: this fixed the problem for me. I wrongly assumed that supplying version.tf in the root dir would propagate do sub-modules... no. The versions need placing in submodules where they're used, otherwise terraform seems to attempt to locate its own version of resources, doesn't find them and fails to init