# Terraform - Error loading modules - no such file or directory (after folder renaming)

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm facing a strange issue while using [terraform](/questions/tagged/terraform).

Consider the following file system:

```
├── Modules
│   └── IAM
│       ├── outputs.tf
│       ├── resources.tf
│       └── variables.tf
├── outputs.tf
├── providers.tf
├── resources.tf

(Created automatically  by Terraform)
├── terraform.tfstate
└── terraform.tfstate.backup
```

I calling the `IAM` module from the `root` module:

```
##resources.tf

# Other Resource configuration...


# Calling IAM module
module "iam" {
  source = "Modules/IAM"
}
```

This is simple and **everything was working well until I renamed the module's *folder* name**.

The original name of the folder was `IAM_Module` and when I changed it to `IAM` things started to break.

The output of `terraform init` (The name of the **module** is `iam` so don't get confused):

```
Initializing modules...
- module.iam
Error downloading modules: Error loading modules: module iam:
open .terraform/modules/94...5b: no such file or directory
```

Checking inside `.terraform/modules` I can see that a symbolic link to the old name of the folder (`IAM_Module`) still exist for some reason:

```
├── 94...5b -> /lab1/Modules/IAM
├── b7...3d -> /lab1/Modules/IAM_Module <--- Previous name of folder
└── modules.json
```

Inside `terraform.tfstate` I can see that the module exist (after root):

```
"modules": [
    {
        "path": [
            "root"
        ],
        "outputs": {},
        "resources": {},
        "depends_on": []
    },
    {
        "path": [
            "root",
            "iam" <----- Here
        ],
        "outputs": {},
        "resources": {
```

I tried to `terraform refresh` but I'm receiving the same `no such file or directory` error.

Terraform version: v0.11.11.

Any help will be appreciated.

---

(*) In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48057222/terraform-v0-11-1-error-downloading-modules-error-loading-modules-open-terr) it seems that they solved the same error (caused by different reason) by manual intervention which I would prefer to avoid.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the old module from your `.terraform`? You may need to `terraform state mv` your resources first though to avoid state issues.

Comment: I guess if I delete it manually it might work, but I searching for a solution that doesn't include manual setup of the internal files.

Comment: This would be a one-time cleanup and not a setup though.

Comment: But if I'll rename one of the modules folders I'll have to re-run it again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the problem again.

First of all I've deleted the `.terraform` file manually and ran `terraform init`.
Now I'm in the state where I was before the file renaming.

After I renamed the file again I ran `terraform plan` and received the following explicit error:

```
Error: Error loading modules: module iam: not found, may need to run 'terraform init'.
```

After running `terraform init` I checked the `.terraform/modules` file and saw 2 symbolic links: 
- One for the new module. 
 - One for the *old module which was now colored in red*.

Both of the modules still appeared under the `modules.json` file.

Not sure why this message haven't popped up at my first attempt but I think that in a situation like this the Terraform [get command](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/get.html) might also help - from the docs:

> The terraform get command is used to download and update modules
>   mentioned in the root module.

In my case the module was already downloaded so I had to run `terraform get` with the `-update` flag:

> If a module is already downloaded and the -update flag is not set,
>   Terraform will do nothing.

---

I think one of the two solutions (`terraform init / get`) need to be considered before deleting auto-generated file like `.terraform`.

I hope this will help someone.